# solr case insensitive sort not working

Tags: lucene

I have one field in solr schema.xml

```
<field name="short_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
    <field name="short_name_copy" type="string_ci" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
   <copyField source="short_name" dest="short_name_copy"/>
```

and field type

```
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and I have set sort field in my code

```
query.addSortField("short_name_copy", ORDER.asc);
```

But When I get search result its not sorted case insensitive.  It gives all camel case result first and then all lower case

If I m having short names

Banu

Ajay

anil

sudhir

Nilesh

It sorts like Ajay, Banu, Nilesh, anil, sudhir

Can anybody please tell me whats wrong here

(My search field is short_name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are using your analyzer only in query time. To do what you want to do, you have to use something like:

```xml
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Or something like:

```xml
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Comment: I tried above.. but still its giving me same result

Comment: I restarted solr. it will reindex right? I imported data again

Comment: No, restarded Solr doesn't reindex the data, you have to reindex all your core !

Comment: a also tried . Delete all index and re index but  there is no result