# Lowercase filter factory doesn't work when docvalues=true

Tags: sorting, solr, solr4

I am trying to achieve case insensitive sorting using Solr and faced [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745713/solr-case-insensitive-sort-not-working).

[Copied]

```
....But When I get search result its not sorted case insensitive. It gives all camel case result first and then all lower case

If I m having short names

Banu

Ajay

anil

sudhir

Nilesh

It sorts like Ajay, Banu, Nilesh, anil, sudhir
...................
```

I followed [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31746001/2098335) and made the following changes in my solr schema.xml file (only relevent field and field type is shown):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">
 <types>
  ...............
  <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField">
   <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  .............
 </types>
 <fields>
 .................
  <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="name" stored="true" type="TextField" docValues="true" />
 ................ 
 </fields>
 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
 </schema>
```

But that didn't solve the sorting issue. So I **removed** `docValues="true"` from the field definition and tried again. This time sorting worked fine, but I had to specify `useFieldCache=true` in the query.

Why `solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory` is not working with `docValues="true"`?

Is there any other ways to make case insensitive sorting to work without removing `docValues="true"` and specifying `useFieldCache=true`?

**Update:**

I  followed ericLavault's advice and implemented Update Request processor. But now I am facing the following issues:

**1)** We are using dse search. So followed the method specified in [this article.](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchUpdatReqProc.html)

Our current table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_data(
    id      UUID,   
    nm      TEXT,   
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Solr schema :

```html
 Solr schema :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">
 <types>
  <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.UUIDField" name="UUIDField"/>
  <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>
 </types>
 <fields>
  <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="nm" stored="true" type="StrField" docValues="true"/>
  <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="id" stored="true" type="UUIDField"/>
  <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="nm_s" stored="true" type="StrField" docValues="true"/>
 </fields>
 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

As advised , I converted nm to lowecase and inserted as nm_s using update request processor. Then reloaded the schema and reindexed . But while querying using this `select nm from test_data where solr_query='{"q": "(-nm:(sssss))"  ,"paging":"driver","sort":"nm_s asc"}';`

I am getting the following error:

```
...enable docvalues true n reindex or place useFieldCache=true...
```

**2)** How can I ensure that the value nm_s is properly updated? Is there any way to see the value of nm_s?

**3)** Why am I getting  the above mentioned error even if docValues is enabled?

Comment: Have you completely re-indexed your content after changing your field definitions (when adding/removing docValues) ?

Comment: @n0tting yes...

Comment: ok sorry for asking this but you never know! :) I think I have a clue on this, just have to check before answering

Comment: @Sharun can you share how you implemented the Update Request processor? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue probably comes from the fact that `DocValues` was designed to support unanalyzed types originally. It does not support `TextField` :

> DocValues are only available for specific field types. The types
>   chosen determine the underlying Lucene docValue type that will be
>   used. The available Solr field types are:
>
> - StrField and UUIDField :
>
>   - If the field is single-valued (i.e., multi-valued is false), Lucene will use the SORTED type.
>   - If the field is multi-valued, Lucene will use the SORTED_SET type.
> - Any Trie* numeric fields, date fields and EnumField.
>
>   - If the field is single-valued (i.e., multi-valued is false), Lucene will use the NUMERIC type.
>   - If the field is multi-valued, Lucene will use the SORTED_SET type.

(quoted from https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/DocValues)

There is an issue on Solr Jira to add docValues support for TextField ([SOLR-8362](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-8362)), but still open and unassigned.

---

To make case insensitive sorting work without removing `docValues="true"`, you will have to use a string field type (`solr.StrField`), but since you can't define any `<analyser>` with string type you will need an [Update Request Processor](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Update+Request+Processors) to lowercase the input stream (or equivalent like preprocessing the field content before sending data to Solr).

If you want your field to be tokenized for search *and* sorted using DocValues, you may use a *copyField* based on your actual text field (without DocValues) and a string field to be sorted on (processed for lowercase and with DocValues enabled).

Comment: "...with the field to be sorted on defined as a string type.." - you mean as `StrField`?

Comment: @Sharun yes, or any field that uses *solr.StrField* (by default we have `<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" />` in schema.xml)

Comment: but we can't specify <analyzer> for StrField, can we?

Comment: As far as I know <analyzer> are only for `TextField` (or custom class derived from it). That's why I suggested to use copyField.

Comment: But without analyzer how can I solve the main issue (case insensitve sort)?

Comment: I think you can try lowercasing using an update request processor.

Comment: Thanks eric, I have followed your advice and implemented URP,. But I am facing some issues. I have updated the question.

Comment: Regarding the content of `nm_s` field you can check if it corresponds to the content of `nm` lowercased using `fl` parameter : `q=*:*&fl=nm,nm_s`. The issue you are facing now seems like a fieldCache issue but don't you think it should belong to a new question?