# solr LowerCaseFilterFactory not working

Tags: sorting, solr, lucene

For case-insensitive sort in solr, I have added the following in the config:

```xml
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and the field as follows:

```xml
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="nm" stored="true" type="TextField" docValues ="true"/>
```

I have tried: [solr case insensitive sort not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31745713/solr-case-insensitive-sort-not-working/31746001#31746001), but it is still not working.

I am new to solr, can anyone please tell me whats going wrong here.

Comment: Have you reindexed? What does the analysis page show for how your content is being processed?

Comment: yeah, only creating a custom URP helped based on this post [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39697408/lowercase-filter-factory-doesnt-work-when-docvalues-true