# Understanding solr field cache

Tags: solr, lucene

While I was working on this [solr LowerCaseFilterFactory not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47284609/solr-lowercasefilterfactory-not-working), I got the following error:

```
...enable docvalues true n reindex or place useFieldCache=true...
```

It was resolved by specifying `useFieldCache=true` in the query.

Is it the lucene [FieldCache](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#fieldcache)?

Can anybody help me know more about this?

Answer (score 0):

When you're using docValues, the field cache isn't used. Since docValues isn't implemented for TextFields yet, the filtering hasn't been applied like you think it would, so the values used for sorting isn't lowercased as you'd assume they'd be.

When you tell Solr to explicitly use the FieldCache, you're saying "don't use the docValues, even if they're available - use the old FieldCache implementation instead".

The correct solution would be to disable docValues for the Text field.

Comment: when docValues are not implemented for TextFields yet, how does that can affect the solution ?

Comment: I made the docValues = false and i got the error  _Field cache is disabled, set the field to be docValues=true and reindex.  Or if the field cache will not exceed the heap usage, then place useFieldCache=true in the request parameters."_

Answer (score 0):

In Lucene-Solr 4.5 and later, docValues are mostly disk-based to avoid the requirement for large heap allocations in Solr. If you use the field cache in sort, stats, and other queries, make those fields docValues

Please check [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchFieldCache.html)